# Dieline- how do I send a dieline to print.

Tags: dieline

Have a dieline I need printed. Do I send a preserved pdf? Or a full packaged folder?

Comment: Ask your printer what is required.

Answer (score 2):

If you're printing the dieline, a PDF should be fine. If I need something cutout, I usually send the working file to the print shop, and most usually accept an Illustrator file.

I would ask the printer what they want.